# htaccess does not work on my hosting, why?

Tags: hosting, cpanel

I uploaded the .htaccess file to the root of my website, but it makes no effect !!
how can I solve this problem

this is the text of .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to contact your host and see if they can enable it for you. They likely have the server configured to not use .htaccess files.